# PayPal integration from Braintree sandbox error: PAYPAL_SANDBOX_ACCOUNT_NOT_LINKED

Tags: javascript, paypal, braintree

I got this error when I try to test my PayPal integration from Braintree.

Here is my client code (actually copy from official site and make little modification):

```
braintree.client.create({
    authorization: ClientToken
}, function(err, clientInstance) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    // Create a PayPal Checkout component.
    braintree.paypalCheckout.create({
        client: clientInstance
    }, function (paypalCheckoutErr, paypalCheckoutInstance) {
        // Stop if there was a problem creating PayPal Checkout.
        // This could happen if there was a network error or if it's incorrectly
        // configured.
        if (paypalCheckoutErr) {
            console.error('Error creating PayPal Checkout:', paypalCheckoutErr); // Error from this line
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
Error creating PayPal Checkout: 
{
    name: "BraintreeError",
    code: "PAYPAL_SANDBOX_ACCOUNT_NOT_LINKED",
    message: "A linked PayPal Sandbox account is required to use PayPal Checkout in Sandbox. See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/#linked-paypal-testing for details on linking your PayPal sandbox with Braintree.",
    type: "MERCHANT",
    details: undefined
}
```

I have actually link my PayPal sandbox account (from the Braintree control panel) and surprisingly cannot find any useful information about this error. Of course I have read through https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/node#linked-paypal-testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally turn out open another Braintree sandbox account solve this problem. It is weird however I cannot solve by anything else.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

There are two sandbox accounts that you need to link together: your [Braintree sandbox](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login), and your [PayPal sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/).

Double check that you have followed the instructions in [Braintree's documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/node#linked-paypal-testing) to link your PayPal sandbox account to your Braintree sandbox account within the [Control Panel](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/overview).

If you continue to see this error, please [contact Braintree Support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact) for assistance.

Comment: I did all you mention before I ask, I have no idea why I fail

Comment: @wdetac I recommend reaching out to [Braintree Support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact), they're going to need identifying information (your sandbox [merchant ID](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials#merchant-id)) to assist you further in finding out why it isn't working.

Comment: Update: I got it to work making another account not associated with paypal connected login :D

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue.

Turns out Paypal need me to verify my phone number and email address. But I haven't login to Paypal since 2016, so my information goes all wrong, finally I have to re-create my paypal account.

Answer (score 0):

Braintree doc: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/testing-go-live#linked-paypal-testing

**You have to link your Paypal account to Braintree**

In order to link a [PayPal sandbox test account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/sandbox/accounts/) to your Braintree sandbox account, you will need the API credentials for that PayPal sandbox test account.

If you don't already have a PayPal sandbox test account for testing your Braintree integration, create a new one by following these steps:

1. Create a PayPal business sandbox account:

   - Log into the [PayPal Developer Dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/)
   - Navigate to Sandbox > Accounts
   - Click Create Account
   - Select the same Country as your Braintree sandbox account
   - Select the account type as Business
2. Go to the [Create New App](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create) page

   - Create an app to get sandbox API credentials
   - Select the same sandbox developer account as the test account created in step 1
3. Note the following Sandbox API Credentials for the new app you created:

   - Email address associated with this app
   - Client ID
   - Secret

Once you have those PayPal sandbox API credentials, enter them in your Braintree sandbox:

1. Log into your [Braintree sandbox Control Panel](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login)
2. Navigate to Settings > Processing > Payment Methods > PayPal
3. Click Link Sandbox
4. Enter the Email address, Client ID, and Client Secret for your PayPal sandbox test account
5. Click Link PayPal Sandbox